# How do I transform this json using Jolt?

Tags: json, jolt

I have an input json as follows

```
{
  "outer1": "value1",
  "outer2": "value2",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "n1",
      "value": "v1"
    },
    {
      "name": "n2",
      "value": "v2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to transform this to the following

```
{
  "outer1": "value1",
  "outer2": "value2",
  "n1": "v1",
  "n2": "v2"
}
```

I am trying to do this using in JOLT. However I am not sure whether such transformations are possible using JOLT..

Can someone please clarify if it is possible using JOLT and share a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out..Similar question at [JOLT transformation to flatten the entire json document with help of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181243/jolt-transformation-to-flatten-the-entire-json-document-with-help-of)

The spec is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "outer1": "outer1",
      "outer2": "outer2",
      "attributes": {
        "*": {
          "name": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,value)": "&1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```